# How to keep alive spring-boot application even after session timeout

Tags: linux, maven, spring-boot, redhat

- I have a Linux machine hosted in the remote environment.
- The details of that machine are as follows:

  `LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
  Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
  Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
  Release:        7.2
  Codename:       Maipo`

  - I am running Spring-Boot service on that machine
    using `mvn spring-boot:run`
  - I am using `putty` to connect and execute the commands on that machine.

My problem is running the service continuously.

If My Windows system is connected to the internet and my PUTTY session is on the remote service went fine but as soon as my session timeout the remote service stops executing.

Is there any way I can keep that service alive full-time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "screen" https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server

This will allow you to continue to run your spring boot application, even if your terminal / putty disconnects:

Here is a cheat-sheet:
http://neophob.com/2007/04/gnu-screen-cheat-sheet/

**To** get started.

**Start** a new screen:

```
# screen
```

**Run** your spring boot app:

```
# mvn spring-boot:run
```

**Detach** your screen:

```
ctrl a ctrl d
```

**Test** if your spring boot app is still running

**To** re-attach to your screen:

```
# screen -r
```

These are the basic commands.